# Reset glViewport after painting on framebuffer

Tags: opengl, viewport

I am painting on a large opengl canvas. At times I need to draw onto some small framebuffers (tiles) and then go back to paint to my canvas. The problem is that when I draw the framebuffers, I obviously change the viewport of the context, so when I go back painting on my canvas obviously the viewport needs to modified. What I am looking for is a way to save and restore the glViewport settings. Something like this in pseudocode:

```
saveViewport();
drawFramebuffers(); // this change the viewport
restoreViewport();
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in feature for that, but using a stack to store viewport sizes+positions should be easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Compatibility contexts [`glPushAttrib()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glPushAttrib.xml)/`glPopAttrib()` with `GL_VIEWPORT_BIT` will save/restore the depth range & viewport state.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @genpfault 's answer, the following also works:

```
// save viewport
GLint aiViewport[4];
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, aiViewport);

// do your stuff and then restore viewport
glViewport(aiViewport[0], aiViewport[1], (GLsizei)aiViewport[2], (GLsizei)aiViewport[3]);
```

This was taken from [here](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/issues/392)

Comment: This also works for the case of opengl-es , since  glPushAttrib()/glPopAttrib() are not supported here